# Cross-Region Secrets Manager Access in Serverless Framework Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm accessing Secrets Manager in my serverless.yml via

```
${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/<path-to-secret>~true}
```

which works out nicely.

Problem is, I'm keeping all my secrets in a single region & now I'm trying to add another region (= stage in serverless), but I don't know how to reference secrets from my main region. To keep costs low, I don't want to replicate my secrets to the secondary regions though.

Is there any way to achieve this without some pre-scripting magic but solely using Serverless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/), the following should work:

```
${ssm.<region-name>:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/<path-to-secret>~true}
```